# Grails legacy mapping error Column is not the same data type as referencing column in foreign key

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, hibernate-mapping, grails-2.0

I am creating a solution using grails that will create tables in the same database schema where other tables already exist. I used the db reverse enginneer plugin to create a domain for my existing legacy tables.

However, when I create new domain classes that have properties that are domains of the reverse engineer table and run the app to publish the model to the database I get the following error:

```
Unsuccessful: alter table WITHDRAW add constraint FK2B28E9D63EA7A90E foreign key (PERSON_id) references PERSON
Error |
2014-11-06 00:20:03,010 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Column 'PERSON.personID' is not the same data type as referencing column 'WITHDRAW.PERSON_id' in foreign key 'FK2B28E9D63EA7A90E'.
```

Here is the **legacy table** that has been reversed engineered

```
package ic

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder

class Person {

String studentNumber
String stateId
String staffNumber
String staffStateId
Integer modifiedById

static mapping = {

    version false

    id column: "personID", generator: "assigned"
    studentNumber column: "studentNumber"
    staffNumber column: "staffNumber"
    stateId column: "stateId"
    staffStateId column: "staffStateId"
    modifiedById column: "modifiedById"


}

static constraints = {

    stateId nullable: true, maxSize: 15
    studentNumber nullable: true, maxSize: 15
    staffNumber nullable: true, maxSize: 15
    staffStateId nullable: true, maxSize: 20
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return new ToStringBuilder(this)
            .append("id", id)
            .append("studentNumber", studentNumber)
            .append("stateId", stateId)
            .append("staffNumber", staffNumber)
            .append("staffStateId", staffStateId)
            .append("modifiedById", modifiedById)
            .toString();
    }
}
```

Here is the new table (not legacy) that gets created but with the errors mentioned above

```
package iccustom

class Withdraw {

    Person person
    WithdrawType withdrawType
    Date withdrawDate
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static belongsTo = [person:Person]

    static mapping = {
        //probably I need to something here but not sure of the correct syntax
    }

    static constraints = {
        person nullable:false, blank:false
        withdrawType nullable:false, blank:false
        withdrawDate nullable:false, blank:false 
    }

}
```

The table gets created fine but I really want the foreign key to get created as well. I want a FK on Withdraw to reference to the personId column in the Person Table

I have tried putting @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn(name="personId) but that did not work either.

Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Try removing `Person person` from your `Withdraw` class and just keep the `belongsTo`. See if that helps.

Comment: @Viriato have you tried to put sqlType when you map the id of Person?

Comment: Yes sqlType is the answer.